# Bulk update products variations in Woocommerce based on categories

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

We have a WordPress website with Woocommerce and we are facing an issue with bulk updating product size variation in our website. We are trying to update Women and men categories size attribute variation when the size attribute is not equal to "One Size"

so we are trying to update the size attribute variation if the variation is equal to any thing except for " One Size"

We are not sure if that can be done by a code snippet or by MySQL queries

We used the below query but it didn't work t all as we don't experience in MySQL

```
UPDATE wp_postmeta 
SET meta_value = 4 UK , 6 UK , 8 UK, 10 UK, 12 UK, 14 Uk. 16 UK, 18 UK 
WHERE post_category = ('Women','men') , AND meta_key = '_size';
```

We also find a plugin called "ELEX WooCommerce Advanced Bulk Edit Products, Prices & Attributes" but we are not sure if it will solve our issue.

Your help will be very appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly what you are trying to do here, you could edit the attributes directly.

For example, if you have the attribute "Size" and want to edit the terms, you can do this directly from your dashboard under **Products > Attributes > Size**.

I hope this is what you were looking for!

Comment: I want to do a bulk edit as we have 6000 products. We wonder if that can be done by MySQL?